# Linearize a specific equation

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

Is it possible to linearize this equation? I tried without success.

$$Y = \dfrac{a \cdot L1 \cdot \left(L1 \over L2\right)^X-L2}{a \cdot \left(L1 \over L2\right)^X-1}$$
I want something in

$Y' = AX' +B$

Answer (score 0):

To linearize
$f(x)$
at a particular
$x_0$,
use
$f(x_0+h)
\approx f(x_0) +hf'(x_0)
$.
This is just the
first two terms 
of the Taylor series.

In your case,
compute
$Y'(X)$
(quotient rule,
derivative of $a^x$)
and use the above formule.